# Adding Offset to VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, offset

Adding Offset to VBA Code.

Currently, I have a block of VBA code that does a good job of seperating different rows in to different tabs.

```
Sub Country_Seperator()

Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer

vcol = 1
Set ws = Sheets("FILTERED")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:E1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

For i = 2 To lr

    On Error Resume Next

    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If

Next

myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear

For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)

    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""

    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!B7)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If

    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("B7")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit

Next

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate

End Sub
```

My main issue is that this code outputs data on A1 and I would like it for it to be offset (eg. output on to B7 over A1)

Comment: A1 to B7 is an OFFSET of 6 rows and 1 column. I am not sure about the mention of nested If etc but simply add the offset to the copy destination.

Comment: So, for example, Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1").Offset(6,1)

Comment: I have edited that line and now the output tabs are empty

Comment: That line would simply have moved the paste not made any difference to whether something was pasted.

Comment: Please please learn about indenting!

Comment: Are you overwriting due to the loop? Though this would have occurred before my suggestion.

Comment: By spacing out code I can now see an unclosed On Error Resume Next. Close it (with On Error GoTo 0) or better still, comment it out first and check no hidden errors when running the code.

Comment: Match doesn't return zero if there's no match.  if you use `Application.Match()` then you can check the return value using `IsError()` and get rid of that `On Error Resume Next`